# HTML & JavaScript How to Make nth Lines of Text Appear with nth Number of Clicks?

Tags: javascript, html, onclick, invisible

I am very new to html and JavaScript, but I am an advanced novice at understanding programming. I am looking for a way to make nth lines of text appear on nth button clicks of a button and when there are no more text lines to show the button does nothing. I imagine that there should be some index to keep track of the amount of clicks and a way to pass a number of clicks that should occur to some function, but I am having trouble finding anything. Can someone point me in the right direction or demonstrate the basics of what I must do. Here is a visual demo of what I want to happen on the webpage:

Click This

Click This
this line appears on first click

Click This
this line appears on first click
this line appears on second click

Click This
this line appears on first click
this line appears on second click
...
this line appears on nth click

Here is some code that does a bit what I am expecting. Is there any changes I can make to make it work more generally?

```js
$(function() {

  $("#visible").click(function() {

    if (typeof this.counter == 'undefined') {
      this.counter = 0;
    }

    $('#invisible' + this.counter).toggleClass("show");

    ++this.counter;
  });

});
```

```css
.hide {
  display: none;
}

.show {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p id="visible">Click This</p>

<p id="invisible0" class="hide">this line appears on the first click</p>

<p id="invisible1" class="hide">this line appears on the second click</p>

<p id="invisible2" class="hide">this line appears on the third click</p>
```

Thanks in advance,
Vectorjon

Comment: Sorry, that's not how Stackoverflow works. You're supposed to give it a try, and show your attempt. If your code doesn't behave as expected, we can help debugging it or pointing out the error. But we're not supposed to write your code for you and develop your solution. If you really have no idea how to do this, you are encouraged to watch a few tutorials and experiment.

Comment: Can you explain a little bit more what is your need behind this? Can you show us what you already tried to do?

Answer (score 2):

This might not be optimal, but at least it's something you can start with.
Basically I set the `font-size` (in this case 12px) and then added that `height + 2px` (14px) to the size of the div container.

https://jsfiddle.net/hassench/r7cgjzus/9/

```js
var expand = () => {
  $('.expandable').css('height', $('.expandable').height() + 14);
}
```

```css
.expandable {
  font-size: 12px;
  height: 15px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='expandable' onclick='expand()'>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam libero ex, vehicula id egestas sed, iaculis vel enim. Curabitur interdum sollicitudin turpis, sit amet semper magna rutrum pharetra. Donec blandit, enim at volutpat feugiat, nunc orci placerat
  nunc, eu placerat tortor libero nec est. Aliquam erat volutpat. Ut dapibus tellus metus, a lacinia risus gravida quis. Nullam placerat maximus risus ut tristique. Mauris rhoncus sagittis erat, eget mollis ligula. Nulla accumsan fermentum dictum.
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I can see some of the benefits and downsides of that approach. I'll give it a try.

Comment: You should be using `max-height` instead.